# How should we treat spoilers?

Tags: discussion, spoilers

When asking for information about an event in a particular series,  how should we behave? Both when asking and when answering a question.

Questions like 
 - why did X kill Y? 
 - why did X do XYZ? 
And all the possible variations,  should they be marked in some way when asking?  Maybe by placing a spoiler warning at the beginning of the question or by using a particular tag?

When we answer,  should we take measures against spoiling the plot?

Comment: Generally, for answers, you should answer the question to the best of your ability, whether or not it constitutes a spoiler. You can use the spoiler markup `>! spoilers here` in posts to hide spoilers if you have to reference something later in the series after what the OP has referenced. For questions, you don't really need to do anything.